# Our web host has suspended us for excessive MySQL usage. Does anybody understand why?

Tags: php, mysql, database, opencart

I apologize if this isn't the right sort of question to ask. I have a good knowledge of web design and operating the scripts I use but I get a little stuck when it comes down to some of the more complex issues.

We recently moved our website from a small shared hosting package to a business shared hosting package with Hostgator. Within a few hours our website was disabled and we have lost a lot of custom on one of our busiest days of the year. The have provided me with the following information but I don't know where to begin. If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
CPU_TIME:339    table_rows_read:363276317       SELECTS:58447   ROWS_UPDATED:61
ROWS_FETCHED:98170      BUSY_TIME:441   ONNECTED_TIME:871       BYTES_SENT:4620832
BYTES_RECEIVED:12790009 WAIT_TIME:102


Top table row reads:
DB_USER: amfizz_retail -- TOTAL_CONNECTIONS: 118 -- CONNECTED_TIME: 872 -- CPU_TIME: 339 --
TABLE_ROW_READS: 363379718 -- SELECT_COMMANDS: 58508 -- UPDATE_COMMANDS:  -- BUSY_TIME: 441 -- 
BYTES_SENT: 4620832 -- BYTES_RECEIVED: 12795625 -- WAIT_TIME (IO): 102



Top WAIT (IO) TIME:
DB_USER: amfizz_retail -- TOTAL_CONNECTIONS: 118 -- CONNECTED_TIME: 872 -- CPU_TIME: 339 -- 
TABLE_ROW_READS: 363379718 -- SELECT_COMMANDS: 58508 -- UPDATE_COMMANDS:  -- BUSY_TIME: 441 -- 
BYTES_SENT: 4620832 -- BYTES_RECEIVED: 12795625 -- WAIT_TIME (IO): 102



amfizz    3696  0.1  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    6583  0.2  0.0 248248 12200 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    7534  0.2  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    7738  0.2  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    8310  0.3  0.0 249020 13380 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    8503  0.2  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz   10245  0.3  0.0 248248 12200 ?        SN   14:55   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz   11040  0.5  0.0 248248 12192 ?        SN   14:55   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz   12791  2.5  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:55   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php

Sat Nov 30 14:55:50 CST 2013
Running Processes:
amfizz    3696  0.1  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    6583  0.2  0.0 248248 12200 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    7534  0.2  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    7738  0.2  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    8310  0.3  0.0 249020 13380 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz    8503  0.2  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz   10245  0.3  0.0 248248 12200 ?        SN   14:55   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz   11040  0.5  0.0 248248 12192 ?        SN   14:55   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php
amfizz   12791  2.5  0.0 248248 12196 ?        SN   14:55   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/amfizz/americanfizz.co.uk/public_html/index.php

Running Queries:
*************************** 1. row ***************************
USER: amfizz_retail
DB: amfizz_retailsite
STATE:
TIME: 6
COMMAND: Sleep
INFO: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
USER: amfizz_retail
DB: amfizz_retailsite
STATE:
TIME: 26
COMMAND: Sleep
INFO: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
USER: amfizz_retail
DB: amfizz_retailsite
STATE:
TIME: 36
COMMAND: Sleep
INFO: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
USER: amfizz_retail
DB: amfizz_retailsite
STATE:
TIME: 53
COMMAND: Sleep
INFO: NULL
*************************** 5. row ***************************
USER: amfizz_retail
DB: amfizz_retailsite
STATE: Sending data
TIME: 0
COMMAND: Query
INFO: SELECT category_id FROM oc_category WHERE parent_id = '148'
*************************** 6. row ***************************
USER: amfizz_retail
DB: amfizz_retailsite
STATE:
TIME: 62
COMMAND: Sleep
INFO: NULL
*************************** 7. row ***************************
USER: amfizz_retail
DB: amfizz_retailsite
STATE:
TIME: 64
COMMAND: Sleep
INFO: NULL
*************************** 8. row ***************************
USER: amfizz_retail
DB: amfizz_retailsite
STATE:
TIME: 74
COMMAND: Sleep
INFO: NULL
*************************** 9. row ***************************
USER: amfizz_retail
DB: amfizz_retailsite
STATE:
TIME: 106
COMMAND: Sleep
INFO: NULL

Open connections


Reference: ui
Server: gator3097.hostgator.com
Srv. Type: cpanel
Created: Thu Nov 28 08:55:31 2013
Acct Type: Shared
Plan: Business
User: amfizz
U. Domain: ****
Email: ****
IP: 50.87.144.132 (shared)

Doc Root: /home1/amfizz/public_html




Table rows read hit 363276317 > 300000000

Current load:  14:55:50 up 178 days, 21:18,  1 user,  load average: 0.12, 0.02, 0.01
```

Comment: I don't think this is a high load to suspend.but I would suggest optimizing your reads, avoiding reading same rows multiple times for one request (caching for single request). BTW how many hits/min you get to your server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, that doesn't look like a massive load for an e-commerce website.

However, like you say, this isn't really the right question to ask.

It's up to Hostgator to determine there fair-use policy, and if you've breached it, that your fault.

You should speak to your hosting company.

**Edit:**

If the `Table rows read hit 363276317 > 300000000` is the reason for this, you can either:

A) Ensure you're not reading way to many unnecessary rows in your queries.

B) Talk to Hostgator and try to agree on a higher limit.

C) Move off of a shared hosting platform and maybe look at hosting your website on a dedicated or virtual server.

Comment: `Table rows read hit 363276317 > 300000000` looks like point to me. Maybe they limit this value to 300G.

Comment: @l-x It looks like that, although for a business hosting package that's not a massive amount...

Comment: Pickup a cheap dedicated server from someone like OVH $30 a month ish then nobody can complain about how much db access you use it'll just run until the hardware falls over which lets face it is unlikely to happen

Comment: Is this an unusual load for an eCommerce website? We receive around 30-60 orders a day.

Comment: This is from one of my mysql servers with a similar uptime to yours Received 143.5 GiB Sent 1.4 TiB Total 1.6 TiB. Questions since startup: 549,795,083. Thats on what I would define as a middling load site.

Comment: @TomTurner the 1st option in my edit might be worth looking at. If you're only processing 30-60 orders a day, I wonder what 300m table rows you're queries are using.

Comment: @stayner its probably search engines/bots indexing list pages / paged files

Comment: @TomTurner And I'd also probably look at option C aswell, if you're processing 30-60 orders a day you could probably do with a dedicated server so you're not sharing resources with other websites, and sharing downtime/server errors etc.

Comment: I think we will move to a dedicated server. We have lost a lot of money due to this and cannot believe that our site was using so many resources

Comment: Just had a look at the actual site its self the homepage alone pulls about 50 products out of the db so between robots and I'm guessing its slightly miscoded too with too many queries.

Comment: I have been drafted in to redesign the site. The site that is online now was created by somebody with absolutely zero web design knowledge. I am aware that the site is sloppy but I never expected it would be too much for a business hosting package. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What e-commerce package is the site using?  Just looking through the products I'm actually going to do some shopping when I get home tonight :)

Comment: We have a brilliant range of products and some great prices too ;) We are using opencart and we have been on a very basic hosting package for 2 years. We moved to Hostgator from a friends recommendation and within 24 hours we were pulled offline.

Comment: Good source of promotion here! ;) 
I would try and stay away from shared hosting, especially in a commercial environment!

Comment: See opencart should be fine under much higher load so I doubt its a major code issue though navigating the site it does seem to take ages to generate the actual page views.  I would definately look at getting yourself a dedicated server.  I'll provide you free hosting in return for free Mountain Dew :)

Comment: We have just purchased a dedicated server to allow us to expand. I would be happy to give everybody here a coupon code for their help. Drop me a message in my inbox. Thanks again

Comment: @TomTurner just remember a dedicated server out of the box will need a little tweaking to its php.ini, apache configs and mysqld configs as by default they're set quite restrictive since your server will be running your site only you may as well relax it a little give it more resources to play with the site speed will increase exponentially.  Since you're UK based I hope you at least got a European based dedi not one of those cheap yank ones as they're horrible usually.

Comment: @TomTurner I don't believe we have an inbox on here :)
And as Dave said, make sure you choose the correct dedi, and plan ahead for whatever tweaks you will need to make.

Comment: @Stanyer we don't I wish we did though :)

Comment: Sorry guys, wasn't aware of that! Drop me an email tomturner@outlook.com and I will sort you all out with some freebies. Thanks again

Comment: @TomTurner feel free to mark this as an answer if you feel it has helped resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is provider claiming unlimited anything and after some time it turns out he is limiting something, this is the great reason to move one next door.

Anyway, OpenCart has some very simple caching to files while products, categories, languages, currencies and few other things are cached once (until some delete, insert or update on them is performed) and then they are read from those files. This caching is done by default and could not be turned on or off.

Anyway if You don't have this *payload* of queries every month (e.g. it occurs once - twice a year) I'd suggest investigating where does all those queries come from as somebody my be trying to either attack Your shop or dig Your data out...